# Mongoose. $push with _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a new instance of my model, then I push it to my book. And `_id` of subdocument in the book is not equal `_id` that I created.

```
var component = new Text(req.body);
var update = {};
    update['pages.' + req.params.pageNum + '.texts'] = {$push: component};

Project
  .update({
    _id: req.params.projectID,
    owner: req.user._id,
  }, update, {safe: false}, function (err, created) {
    console.log(123);
    err
      ? res.json(500, {error: err.message})
      : res.json(created ? 201 : 404, {data: component});
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) should be the top-level operator field of your `update` object:

```
var update = {$push: {}};
update.$push['pages.' + req.params.pageNum + '.texts'] = component;
```